# pwdCheckModule: attribute is obsolete in Openldap 2.6

Tags: openldap

I need to create OpenLDAP Password Policies to load third party password check module pqchecker to check the strength for the password content of user which OpenLDAP default password policy can not do it.
But start from Openldap 2.5, the attribute of pwdCheckModule can not be used in ldif file of Openldap password policy, pwdUseCheckModule/pwdCheckModuleArg need to be used to instead of it.
How to configure it in Openldap 2.6? There is less documents on Internet can be referred. Is there anyone can help me on this?